# Number converter wrapping ignores locale? bug?

Tags: jsf, locale, converters

Is it a Bug that the first does selects between a dot or comma (always dot) according to the used f:view locale? Or is there a rule how to nest number converters.

**1.**

```
<f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal">
    <f:convertNumber maxIntegerDigits="3" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
</f:converter>
```

**2.**

```
<f:convertNumber maxIntegerDigits="3" maxFractionDigits="2">
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal"/>
</f:convertNumber>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest converters. They will just be applied on the closest parent `UIComponent` in the order as they're declared. You can also not specify multiple converters. Only the last one would really be used. Each [`ValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ValueHolder.html) component can have only one converter while each [`EditableValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) can have more than one validators.

Just stick to `<f:convertNumber>`. When used on input components which are already bound to a property of `BigDecimal` type, it'll respect the type.

Comment: Thanks. This explains the behaviour.

Comment: It would be much easier if jsf automatically detects float types and the used locale. Especially if defined using converterId with numeric type. Looks so boiler plate adding `<f:convertNumber/>` to each float value component..

Comment: A fictive `<h:inputNumber>` with some formatting related attributes was been less verbose, yes. Maybe a new idea for OmniFaces :) You can also always extend `NumberConverter` or `BigDecimalConverter` wherein you set fixed attributes and use it in `<h:inputText converter>` instead.